# How to stream an RTSP source (e.g., Raspberry Pi camera) over the Internet without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, raspicam, remote

I have a Raspberry Pi with the camera module attached and I can view the RTSP stream fine when I'm within my local network. What I want to achieve and am struggling to figure it out is how to stream the camera through RTSP over the Internet.

I use a service called remot3.it to tunnel into my Pi remotely, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the stream itself tunneled. I have tried to open a custom TCP port through remot3.it but I can't seem to view the RTSP stream at all with it. The tl;dr of how remot3.it and (others) work is that you specify a port and you go through their dynamic proxy to access whatever application is listening on that port.

I read posts about how RTSP sockets are unreliable and that maybe the reason why I can't successfully view my stream over the remot3.it proxy.

Is it possible to do this remotely without port forwarding manually?

Comment: Have you configured the remote3 port via the proxy config to tunnel the same port you are streaming over? It's not entirely clear if you have or haven't done this. Also how have you setup the RTSP stream in the first place?

Comment: Yeah sorry - ill edit the post but yeah I have tried to specify the custom TCP port to be opened but it wont work. I can view it fine when i manually type the IP address into VLC player to test the stream but the moment I try to to the remot3 proxy it fails to connect.